# Rails Param Won't Save. NULL when should be array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is driving me mad. It worked before but I changed the attribute to `:service` because originally I was accidentally using the wrong field...

I have an invoice

```
  create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "reference_number"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.boolean  "paid"
    t.string   "payment_method"
    t.string   "service"
    t.decimal  "total"
    t.text     "special_instructions"
    t.integer  "contractor_id"
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.index ["contractor_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_contractor_id"
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_customer_id"
  end
```

And I want to save an array of strings to the service column. I have correctly permitted my params in my controller, but I keep getting `NULL` for the service when I save the invoice...(EVERY other field saves correctly, and if I change it to a `text_field` instead of check boxes, it saves. Makes me believe my view is the issue?) The way it's set up now there are multiple check boxes to select and that should save like this for example: `["item1", "item2"]` but it does not work.

inside my `form_for(invoice) do |f|`

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="items">
      <% items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'] %>
      <%= f.label :service, "Service Provided" %>
      <div class="form-inline form-check-inline">
        <% items.each do |item| %>
          <div class="item-options">
             <%= f.check_box :service, { class: 'form-check-input', multiple: true}, item, nil %>
             <%= f.label item, class: "form-check-label" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And my params inside my `invoices_controller.rb`

```
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:customer_id, :contractor_id, [...], service: [])
end
```

But it will not save. I must be doing something really silly that's making this not work. I had it working before but now I've spent too much time trying to figure it out. Thanks.

**EDIT: IT WORKS IF I DO IT THIS WAY... But I just want some dang checkboxes.**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :service %>
    <%= f.text_field :service %>
</div>

def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:customer_id, :contractor_id, [...], :service)
end
```

Comment: how is your params looking like when submitting the form ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: how is your log file displays invoice params ?

Comment: I'm actually not seeing `service` inside the params...All the rest of the params are there though?...

Comment: I can't see what is wrong with the above. I would suggest doing this
put 'byebug' in your create action and then go to console and you can see what is wrong with checking @invoice.service or @invoice.valid? etc

Comment: After saving the record and hitting byebug in the create action, `@invoice.service` is nil. I can set the service myself with `@invoice.service = "Item"` so I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In the original post, you say "I changed the attribute" - can you explain a little more about that? I feel that is connected to your problem if it worked before.

Comment: Basically, I have other nested attributes inside my invoice and originally I had that `form` chunk above working and saving an array of strings but it was saving it to the nested resource instead of in the invoice table. So I just pulled the code out of there and have it working off of the main f.builder now. I obviously changed it to `:service` and corrected my params but there is something wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see. Having read that and taken another look, I am wondering it the issue is that the service field is a string. With check boxes, I always use booleans - could that be the issue?

Comment: Well, I was having the ability to check multiple checkboxes, and saving multiple strings. Think of it as services. The invoice has multiple services you can check.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is datatype of `service` is string, but you want you save a `Array` data. In case, your database not support `Array` datatype, Rails can help you auto convert data to `String` when data is saved and convert `String` to `Array` when data is read.

```
# In your model
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :service
    ...
end
```

I added some images about example( Rails 5.1.4, Database: Mysql)

In controller

[image: In controller]

Form

[image: html]

[image: Form]

Data is saved in database

[image: Data is saved in database]

Read data

[image: Read data]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Might be on to something but I tried your code but it did not work... The weird thing was that I had it working before and never had to serialize. I opened my DB file in a database browser and saw the array of strings were saving just fine.

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach I create an example in your case, please check it!

Answer (score 0):

So I guess there must have been some weird problem in my view as I suspected. I rolled back to a previous commit and took my old view code (without any bootstrap and in rough shape-format wise) and it worked... So I'm guessing that the nesting of multiple `<form>` tags and form-groups was the culprit? I don't really have any other explanation.

I did end up going with different code for my multiple checkboxes though. It works great and doing it this way I am able to see the items selected when I go to edit the invoice were as the old code did not select the boxes.

```
<% services = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'] %>
<h4>Service Provided</h4>
<div class="form-inline form-check-inline">
  <% for service in services %>
    <%= check_box_tag "invoice[service][]", service, invoice.service.to_s.include?(service), :multiple => true, :include_blank => TRUE %>
    <%= f.label service, class: "form-check-label" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```